# LinkedIn API not providing the user URN

Tags: oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, urn

am trying to use linkedin API to make users share content from our platform to their profiles in LinkedIn, in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/consumer/integrations/self-serve/share-on-linkedin?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext#request-body-schema)  the API requires a user URN in the request body.
But when i follow how to get it i see a legacy APIs `shares/userId` that seems do not work anymore ( They don't even provide an id to test the legacy API in the response) 
**I have this scopes**
`email, openid, profile, r_ads, r_events, r_learningdata, r_liteprofile, r_marketing_leadgen_automation, w_member_social`

*I saw many people having the same problem but there is no response on the issue or any clarification*

## Endpoints a tried

1. `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo`
   **Response:**

```
{
    "sub": "XXX-XXXX",
    "email_verified": true,
    "name": "XXXX XXXXX",
    "locale": {
        "country": "FR",
        "language": "fr"
    },
    "given_name": "XXXX",
    "family_name": "XXXX",
    "email": "XXXXXX@gmail.com",
    "picture": "XXXXXXX"
}
```

2. `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`
   **Response:**.

```
{
    "localizedLastName": "XXXX",
    "profilePicture": {
        "displayImage": "XXXXX"
    },
    "firstName": {
        "localized": {
            "fr_FR": "XXXX"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "FR",
            "language": "fr"
        }
    },
    "lastName": {
        "localized": {
            "fr_FR": "XXXX"
        },
        "preferredLocale": {
            "country": "FR",
            "language": "fr"
        }
    },
    "id": "XXX-XXXX",
    "localizedFirstName": "XXXX"
}
```

### No user URN returned in both

Answer (score 0):

The URN refers to the ID returned from the `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me` response OR the `sub` field from `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/userinfo`.